# FailedPreconditionError when using tf.train.match_filenames_once()

Tags: tensorflow

I am following a TensorFlow book and have a problem with one code example as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# import os
# cwd = os.getcwd()

# print(cwd)

filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once("../audio_dataset/*.wav")
count_num_files = tf.size(filenames)
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
filename, file_contents = reader.read(filename_queue)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    num_files = sess.run(count_num_files)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for i in range(num_files):
        audio_file = sess.run(filename)
        print(audio_file)
```

I am getting the error as follows:

```
FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value matching_filenames_18
    [[Node: matching_filenames_18/read = Identity[T=DT_STRING, _class=["loc:@matching_filenames_18"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](matching_filenames_18)]]
```

What am I missing please?

Marcin

Answer (score 3):

The [`tf.train.match_filenames_once()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/match_filenames_once) function internally creates a "local variable" that stores the matched filenames, but this local variable must be initialized. To do so, change the code as follows:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()])
    # [As before...]
```